# How to append to a json object to existing json in angular js

Tags: angularjs, state

How to append to a json object to existing json in angular js

I am having an object like this

```
$scope.object1 = {
  data1: 'abc',
  data2: 1
};


$scope.object2 = {    
  data3:"One",
  data4:["a","b","c"]
};
```

How to append $scope.object2 to $scope.object1

So the final data should be like this

```
$scope.object1 = {
  data1: 'abc',
  data2: 1,
  data3:"One",
  data4:["a","b","c"]
};
```

I am using this but its not working

```
angular.forEach($scope.object1, function(obj)
{              
    obj.data3 = $scope.object2.data3;

    obj.data4 = $scope.object2.data4;

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `angular.extend($scope.object1, $scope.object2)`

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {
  $scope.object1 = {
    data1: 'abc',
    data2: 1
  };

  $scope.object2 = {    
    data3:"One",
    data4:["a","b","c"]
  };
  
  angular.extend($scope.object1, $scope.object2);
  document.write(JSON.stringify($scope.object1));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how, sir please explain any dependency needed?

Comment: It is built-in function. There are no extra dependencies. Let me show it in a snippet.

Comment: hearts off.Thankyou Sir Working

Answer (score 2):

Use JQuery extend method.  https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/

```
$.extend( $scope.object1, $scope.object2 );
```

Comment: No additional dependencies (e.g. jQuery) are required. There is own function `angular.extend` for that

Comment: I didn't know about it. It is good to know that we have this function in angular. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Lodash probably has the easiest way of doing this:

```
var users = {
 'data': [{ 'user': 'barney' }, { 'user': 'fred' }]
};

var ages = {
  'data': [{ 'age': 36 }, { 'age': 40 }]
};


_.merge(users, ages);
```

result will be

```
{ 'data': [{ 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36 }, { 'user': 'fred', 'age': 40 }] }
```